# How to load a backup DB file in AWS RDS Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I've got a PostgreSQL backup file (tar zipped) and I would like to restore it in fresh Amazon RDS instance. I loaded the backup file in S3 but I don't know how to restore it in Postgresql RDS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a very good document for this procedure.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html

Comment: Ok, thanks, I read it but my database  is full of store procs, triggers, functions, partitions and so on ... umh I am quite stuck.